# connectionString server name not picked up

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

As per reference ([Modifying connection string with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247349/modifying-connection-string-with-variables)), my `App.config` file line of interest:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MagiqDatabaseEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/UnPalangiModel.csdl|res://*/UnPalangiModel.ssdl|res://*/UnPalangiModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source={0}\{1};initial catalog=MagiqDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

(Note `{0}` and `{1}`)

I have the following in my .cs file:

```
string connectionString = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MagiqDatabaseEntities"].ConnectionString, "HPPC", "NEWINSTANCE");
```

The server is `HPPC\NEWINSTANCE`

As per reference ([Can't make a connection string in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375366/cant-make-a-connection-string-in-c-sharp)), I thought the backslash could be a problem. I have tried double backslash, but I still can't establish a connection.

The connection **definitely** works when `data source` is hardcoded to `HPPC\NEWINSTANCE`.

Thank you.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and debug, what string is ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MagiqDatabaseEntities"].ConnectionString actually returning? Does it return a string with the {0}\{1} that we'd expect?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just simply set `Data Source = {0}`

And in your C# code do this:

```
string connectionString = string.Format(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MagiqDatabaseEntities"].ConnectionString, 
    string.Concat("HPPC", @"\", "NEWINSTANCE"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Debugger reveals:

"metadata=res://*/UnPalangiModel.csdl|res://*/UnPalangiModel.ssdl|res://*/UnPalangiModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"data source=HPPC\\NEWINSTANCE;initial catalog=MagiqDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework\""

Comment: Good suggestion, of course the concatenation could be completely unnecessary, unless they need the server and instance names to be modular.

Comment: @Michael Ineed.

Comment: @taylorswiftfan what do you mean by debugger reveals? Did it work for you?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified - No it did not work for me.

Comment: @taylorswiftfan Where do you stuck on with this solution?

Comment: The problem being the program still cannot talk to the database.

Comment: @taylorswiftfan You should be able to troubleshoot this. You said hardcoding the server\instance into the connectionstring works fine? So then do that, set a breakpoint and debug. See what you get. Then compare that to what u are getting when you use string.format().